# Laravel How to include Schema.org structured data on multiple pages

Tags: php, laravel, schema.org

I'm building a `laravel`-application where I want to include some `schema.org` structured data. In my `app.blade.php` - file, which is a layout file  - I have included this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebSite",
    "name": "thecompany.com",
    "alternateName": "the company",
    "url": "{{ route('home') }}"
}
</script>
```

Now I want to add different parameters, pending on which subpage I am. For example I have a Job-listing page where I want each single jobpage to have something like:

```
{
  "@context" : "https://schema.org/",
  "@type" : "JobPosting",
  "title" : "Software Engineer",
  "description" : "<p>Become our next developer.</p>",
  "employmentType" : "CONTRACTOR",
  "hiringOrganization" : {
     "@type" : "Organization",
     "name" : "The Company",
     "sameAs" : "http://www.google.com",
     "logo" : "http://www.example.com/images/logo.png",
     "baseSalary": {
       "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
       "currency": "USD",
       "value": {
          "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
          "value": 40.00,
          "unitText": "HOUR"
       }
   }
}
```

and the values change of course pending on which job page you are.

I tried to add the script in the `job.blade.php`-file but it seems that it gets overridden by the script which is located in the `app.blade.php`-file

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you look into [Blade components](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#components-and-slots)?

You could build a schema component with some defaults and include it on your job sites:

`schema.blade.php`

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    "@context" : "https://schema.org/",
    {{ $slot }}
</script>
```

`job.blade.php`

```
@component('schema')
    "@type" : "JobPosting",
    "title" : "Software Engineer",
    "description" : "<p>Become our next developer.</p>",
    ....
@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 12):

An alternative would be to use a package like [Schema.org generator for Laravel](https://github.com/spatie/schema-org)

This allows you to write code like this:

```
use Spatie\SchemaOrg\Schema;

$localBusiness = Schema::localBusiness()
    ->name('Spatie')
    ->email('info@spatie.be')
    ->contactPoint(Schema::contactPoint()->areaServed('Worldwide'));

echo $localBusiness->toScript();
```

...which generates the following JSON-LD:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http:\/\/schema.org",
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "name": "Spatie",
    "email": "info@spatie.be",
    "contactPoint": {
        "@type": "ContactPoint",
        "areaServed": "Worldwide"
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a solution to render it in templates

Comment: Personally, I generate the code in a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers) and then simply print it out in my layout view above the closing `</body>` tag like so: `{!! $schema !!}`.

Comment: I can vouch for Spatie's package, works great and is well documented.